# R ggplot2 hexbin plot graphics bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I always spot a handful of strange white horizontal dotted lines that seem to appear on the borders between vertically adjacent hexagons on every hexbin density plot that I create using ggplot2 in the R environment. They certainly do not belong there... This behavior (bug) is reproducible on several R installations on different computers with different MS Windows versions and different graphics drivers. I don't have a clue on how to get rid of these dotted lines.
Below is a plot showing the problem, and the code that produced the plot.
Is this a known problem? Any hint to overcome this? Thanks a bunch for any help!

[image: Plot with bespoke bug]

```
## Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)

## Create some data
set.seed(222)
myx <- data.frame(x = 0.4 + rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1))
myy <- data.frame(y = 0.5 + rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1))
MyData <- data.frame(xvariable=myx$x*100, yvariable=myy$y*100)

## Prepare the plot window
dev.off(2)
windows.options(width=6, height=6)
op <- par(mfrow = c(1,1))
op <- par(oma = c(0,0,0,0) + 0.1,
          mar = c(5.1, 5.1, 4.1, 2.1))

## Creaate the plot
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=xvariable, y=yvariable) ) +
  geom_hex(bins=66) +
  xlim(0, 100) +
  ylim(0, 100) +
  ggtitle("My plot") +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=17, face="bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=17, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=17, face="bold"),
        axis.text=element_text(color="black", size=15, face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 15), 
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size=12),
        legend.position = c(0.9,0.2), legend.direction = "vertical")
```

Comment: This is an issue with the R plotting canvas, not solely with `ggplot2` or `hexbin`. In fact, if I run your code and resize the plot window, the lines shift, change in number, or completely disappear, reminiscent of other raster artifacts. When I save this to a PDF, the lines are always missing (in my testing). If you're able to switch to vector-based graphic formats (e.g., pdf, svg) then perhaps that's your best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you save as pdf and then convert that to image, there will be no line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks both! I used the ggsave() function which makes nice pdf-files (without the bespoke bug). But as I need a vector format to insert the plot in a Word document, I exported the plot to the wmf format. But the resulting wmf file again shows the bug. Export to svg works perfectly, but Word 2016 can neither handle svg-files nor import vector-based pdf-files. So the only way for the moment is exporting to a pdf, make a snapshot of the plot and copy it to Word as bitmap image. Any solutions to end up with a vector format file that Word can handle?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too, RStudio version 1.4.1717 "Juliet Rose" (df86b69e, 2021-05-24) for Windows. Looks like white lines going across the 'Plots' tab if I use `geom_hex()`. If I resize the output window by a pixel at a time (vertically) , the lines will disappear.

Maybe there's too many hex bins to begin with and the resolution causes gaps every so often.

before
[image]

after
[image]